# content builder marketing cloud add external url link to head part

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to know if it is possible in marketing cloud content builder to add a link to an external library which would be placed in the head section of a page
for example for an external javascript or css library

<_ html >
<_ head >
link appearing here
<_ / head >
<_ body >
<_ / body >
<_ / html >

i tried to look at the different choices but it is always placed in the body part of the generated page.

if yes which content block should I use?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You would need to edit the template in "code view" and then save it.  After that, you would need to go and update each email via "update template" option in properties tab.

If you are using a default template, you will need to save it as a new template. You will then need to go into each email and select "change template" and then select the new template you saved.

Also please note that linked stylesheets, etc have only partial support in emails. You will be better off embedding the stylesheet in the head, which is much [more widely supported](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

JavaScript is not supported almost at all and can actually cause your email to be flagged as spam or blocked by the receiving email filters.